# Keys don't exist with ASP having multiple URL parameters with no values

Tags: asp-classic

I have a URL like so:
`www.domain.com/thispage.asp?param1&param2=test&param3=airplanes`

A couple questions:

1. Expectedly, I cannot access `Request.QueryString("param1")`, but I also cannot access any `null` keys. How do I get this value?  The URI can't change unfortunately.
2. When I iterate through the parameters for the keys, it shows I only have two:
   `param1&param2` and `param3`. It's like the ampersand does not distinguish between parameters and so it sees that as one key. How can I get the values of the first two parameters? I don't want to use regex if I don't have to.

For the third parameter in this example, `Request.QueryString("param3")` works as it should.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My question is different, I've read the other post linked and like I stated above, I can't access a `null` key.  Also, I have to use parenthesis to access the keys, not brackets.  We are not using c#, so apologies if I tagged this incorrectly (I frankly don't know all the differences). Also, as stated, we cannot change the URI by adding a "=" or anything else - it will have multiple parameters, with one being just a plain value (or key, whatever it's called in this case).

One more thing I should add: When the URL is simply `www.domain.com/thispage.asp?param1`, then `Request.QueryString` is equal to "`param1`"

Comment: The URI would need to be `param1=&`, I think. Or just omit param1 from the request entirely if it isn't populated.

Comment: P.S. you talk about a URL with `.asp` extension, usually indicating ASP Classic, but then tagged the question with ASP.NET. They are very different beasts. Which one are you really using here?

Comment: @ElasticCode only if it really is ASP.NET ...see my comment above. Although ASP Classic may well behave in a similar way, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: The second answer from ElasticCodes link really looks promising

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"but I also cannot access any null keys"*?

Comment: @grek40 Sure.  When I try to access `Response.QueryString(null)` I get a 500 error.  Likewise when I try and use `GetValues` or anything else with regards to the `null` key.

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo you may want to access `Request`, not `Response`. Please clarify whether this was an error in your comment or in your code.

Comment: You should be able to get the full querystring value using `Request.QueryString` then parsing the return string *(which will be `param1&param2=test&param3=airplanes`)* manually *(`Split()` on the `&` to get each key value pair)*. @grek40 Let's be clear the suggested duplicate is not helpful as they are solutions for ASP.Net **not** Classic ASP.

Comment: I've just tested this and `Response.Write(Request.QueryString("Param1"))` does not return an error, but obviously, it doesn't write anything to the screen either because the querystring parameter is `Empty`. Not sure you're telling us the whole story here, what is the actual error?

Comment: @grek40 My bad, I meant Request. That was indeed an error on my part  @Lankymart Yes, I could use something like `instr()` or `split()` to achieve what I need.  `Request.QueryString("Param1")` does not exist because it sees `param1&param2` as the key - apparently the ampersand does not separate the keys.